# Getting the item under mouse cursor in a listview control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

Basically I am trying to implement a feature where if the user presses a key, I want to find out the item under the mouse cursor.

So I don't use Mouse events but Keyboard events which doesn't give me a ListViewItem of course.

I just don't know in what space I need to get the mouse position and convert it into the control's space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

If you know which ListView control you are interested in, the following method will do the trick:

```
private ListViewItem GetItemFromPoint(ListView listView, Point mousePosition)
{
    // translate the mouse position from screen coordinates to 
    // client coordinates within the given ListView
    Point localPoint = listView.PointToClient(mousePosition);
    return listView.GetItemAt(localPoint.X, localPoint.Y);
}

// call it like this:
ListViewItem item = GetItemFromPoint(myListView, Cursor.Position);
```

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, I will try this today.

Comment: Note that if you're doing this inside a mouse event handler, e.g. MouseDoubleClick, the MouseEventArgs.Location is already client-relative, thus you don't want to call PointToClient()

Answer (score 0):

A keyboard action that depends on the mouse position sounds a little unorthodox. Keyboard actions should normally effect some item that is highlighted/focused/selected on the screen, either selected by previous keyboard actions or by a previous mouse click on that item.

Just something to bear in mind, or you'll wind up with a "unique" (confusing) user interaction.

Comment: Don't worry man, I am adding this feature for myself to ease the development for myself. It's not gonna be in the final version :)