# Unselect listview item when hovering in listview background

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am needing some help with a listview control that uses large icon view.  I have icons in my listview control that when I hover over them, it displays a custom tooltip (not the in-built listview tooltip).

My problem is that when I hover into the background of the listview, it doesn't de-select the selected item.  I would also like to cut the tooltip short (if possible) so if the tooltip is meant to be visible for 5 seconds and someone hovers into the background of the listview before this time, then the item deselects and the tooltip disappears.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Private Sub lsvStores_ItemMouseHover(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs) Handles lsvStores.ItemMouseHover
    Dim storeID As String = e.Item.Name
    ShowStoreDetailsTooltip(storeID, sender, e.Item.Position.X, e.Item.Position.Y - 80)
End Sub

Private Sub lsvStores_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lsvStores.MouseHover
    lsvStores.SelectedItems.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowStoreDetailsTooltip(ByVal Code As String, ByVal Obj As Control, ByVal XPos As 
    ttpStoreDetails.ToolTipTitle = StoreName
    ttpStoreDetails.IsBalloon = True
    ttpStoreDetails.Show(String.Empty, Obj, 0)
    ttpStoreDetails.Show(tmpString, Obj, XPos, YPos, 5000)
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045621/getting-the-item-under-mouse-cursor-in-a-listview-control), we can get the item currently under the mouse cursor using [ListView.GetItemAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.getitemat%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), then see if it's `Nothing`.  If it is, then you'll do whatever you need to to make your Tooltip disappear.

```
Private _item As ListViewItem = Nothing

Private Sub lsvStores_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lsvStores.MouseMove
    Dim item As ListViewItem = lsvStores.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)

    If item Is Nothing Then
        If _item IsNot Nothing Then
            _item.Selected = False
        End If

        _item = Nothing

       ttpStoreDetails.Hide(sender)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that has pretty much done the trick.  Just added an extra line to deselect all items when moving off an item.  My question is, is it possible to use the same procedure (lsvStores_MouseMove) to also get the item and show the tooltip if the mouse moves over an actual item, or do I need to use the original ItemMouseHover procedure to capture the selected item?

Comment: @user2185200 You can use this same method to capture the mouse going over an actual item.  In that case your `item` wouldn't be `Nothing` because there would be an actual `ListViewItem` under the mouse cursor.  This does, however, come with the proviso that it would make your tooltip show up immediately when the customer mouses over the item, instead of the usual delay you get with hovering.

Comment: I tried to put in an 'else' statement if 'item' is not nothing then show the tooltip, but it flicks the tooltip every millimetre I move the mouse over the item.  I just need it to display whilst it's on the item and not refresh everytime.

Comment: I also tried putting the tooltip.show code back into the ItemMouseHover procedure which seems to work fine.  However, the only limitation is that if I hover off an item and back onto the same item, the tooltip doesn't show.  It only shows when I hover onto a new item.

Comment: @user2185200 If you want to make use of this method to display your `ToolTip` then I'd suggest you set a boolean flag every time you show/hide your `ToolTip`.  Then you can check that flag in the method and if the `ToolTip` is already showing then don't show it again.