# Getting the item under mouse cursor in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

This may looks like duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788337/1997232) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1045621/1997232) question. But my issue is what to do with obtained `ListViewItem`?

I've set `ListView` binding like this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ...>
```

where

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Data { ... }
```

How do I get `Item` (from `ListViewItem`)?

---

I tried to use mvvm and bind currently mouse-overed item similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511752/1997232). But then I stumbled even more:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <!-- this will not work -->
                    <Setter Property="{Binding MouseoveredItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Is my intent clear? How do I get mouse-howered `Item`?

---

I can't believe nobody has done this. Here is code-behind attempt (to illustrate my problem):

```
private void ListView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var item = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(listView, Mouse.GetPosition(listView)).VisualHit;
    // find ListViewItem (or null)
    while (item != null && !(item is ListViewItem))
        item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    if (item != null)
    {
        ... // item is ListViewItem, how to convert ListViewItem it to Item
    }
}
```

I can find `ListViewItem`, but I need properties of mouse-overed `Item`, which are displayed as `SubItems` or are hidden. How do I convert `ListViewItem` (visual view of `Item`) to `Item` (which is  this `ListViewItem` represents)?

Comment: have you tried `e.OriginalSource` in your `ListView_MouseMove` event Handler??

Comment: @AmolBavannavar, to do what? It has `Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ListBoxChrome` type, how should I use that to obtain `Item`?

Comment: On `e.OriginalSource`, you can traverse upwards by taking help of `VisualTreeHelper` and you will reach that item.

Comment: @AmolBavannavar, how? Will I get `Item`? I already do *tranversing* (see last edit) with `VisualTreeHelper`, but I get `ListViewItem` (and **not** `Item`) as you can see.

Comment: Refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AmolBavannavar, thanks, but this is not helpful at all, nor the suggestion, not the given link.

Comment: isn`t ListViewItem.DataContext your Item?

Comment: @huzle, yes, that's it, thanks a lot. My problem was this and that `VisualHit` returns `DependencyObject` (while I assumed it's `ListViewItem` and looked into wrong type properties). You can make an answer or I'll just delete a question after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you got the "ListViewItem" the Property "DataContext" of it will return your "Item".

Answer (score 0):

In the following code snippet the `ListView` object is bound with an `ObservableCollection<IDataItem>` collection where `IDataItem` is a custom interface and inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

in .xaml:

```
MouseMove="listView_OnMouseMove"
```

in .xaml.cs:

```
private void listView_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{        
    if (!(e.Source is UIElement selectedObject))
        return;

    var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(selectedObject);
    var dataContextObject = listView.GetObjectAtPoint<ListViewItem>(mousePosition);

    if (!(dataContextObject is IDataItem dataItem))
        return;

    // Deal with the selectedObject under the mouse cursor here
}


// How to get Item under cursor in WPF ListView
// https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1453642 - Answer #2
public static object GetObjectAtPoint<ItemContainer>(this ItemsControl control, Point p) 
    where ItemContainer : DependencyObject
{
    // ItemContainer - can be ListViewItem, or TreeViewItem and so on(depends on control)
    var obj = control.GetContainerAtPoint<ItemContainer>(p);
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    return control.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(obj);
}

private static ItemContainer GetContainerAtPoint<ItemContainer>(this ItemsControl control, Point p) 
    where ItemContainer : DependencyObject
{
    var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(control, p);
    var obj = result.VisualHit;

    while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj) != null && !(obj is ItemContainer))
    {
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }

    // Will return null if not found
    return obj as ItemContainer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Data { ... }

public Item SelectedData { get; set; }
```

And in your View

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}" ...>
```

When the selection changes, as will the SelectedData property.

Comment: Moving mouse over `ListView` will not change selection.